# Newbie Toggle question

Tags: jquery, toggle

What am I missing here? When I click on the 'h2 a' link, the .content ol should toggle. I can't figure out why it isn't working :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".content ol").hide();
$(".content h2 a").click(function(){
$(this).find(".content ol").toggle(400);
});
});
</script>

  <div class="content"> 
    <h2><a href="#">click me</a></h2>
    <ol>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </ol> 
  </div>
```

Comment: $(".content ol").toggle(400); should work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `find` looks for elements that are descendants of the current selected eleemnt.  You are looking within `this`, which is the link that was clicked on.  Obviously, the `ol` is not within the `a` element.

You need to use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), to go up the tree to the `div` and only *then* use `find`:

```
$(".content h2 a").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.content').find("ol").toggle(400);
});
```

Comment: Thanks lonesomeday, I would never have figured that. Of course then the problem is that it toggles every '.content ol' on the page (as I have several... I should have mentioned that!). Is there a straightforward solution to that?

Comment: @andy So do you want the `ol` that is the next element after the `h2` that is the parent of the `a` element? So up one level and along one, so to speak? That would be `$(this).parent().next().toggle(400);`

Comment: This is what I have already: http://www.4pixels.com/web-design/about-me.html# and thats fine, but the coding was really cumbersome and not streamlined, hence me trying to learn a simpler way!!

Comment: @andy It looks to me like you want to use the code in my above comment. You probably also want to look into [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault) to stop the browser going to the top of the page on each click.

Comment: Thank you @lonesomeday that seems to work, but any idea why the ol slides down the sideways? You can see the new page here: http://www.4pixels.com/web-design/xabout-me.html# compared to http://www.4pixels.com/web-design/about-me.html# Not a major issue, am just curious :/ And thank you for all your help. I'm learning loads!

Comment: must be that I targetted ol>* in my old script

Comment: @andy Try `slideToggle` instead -- seems a bit smoother to me.

Answer (score 0):

@andy, I've created a jsfiddle that cleans up the slide a bit for you. Should work across all modern browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/9QgmQ/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content ol").hide();
        $(".content h2 a").click(function(){
        $('.content').find(" ol").slideToggle(400);
    });
});
```

You may want to consider using $.(object).slideToggle() instead of toggle(), for a smooth up/down toggle.